# How do I hide title of a node?

Tags: nodes

I have tried doing this in hook_node_view or  hook_node_view_alter with no luck:

I have tried things like:
     `unset( $node->title);` or
      `$node->title ='';`

note: my node was created using panel nodes

Answer (score 3):

The [Exclude Node Title](https://drupal.org/project/exclude_node_title) module has that functionality if you'd prefer a non-code solution.

> This module handles a very simple functionality, decide whatever to exclude a node title from full node page or node teasers.

Comment: I also thought about mentioning it but didn't because I though he is asking about node display page only..

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help you.

In Drupal 7 , if you dont want any modules then you can use **template preprocess functions** for you requirement.

- [template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7)

  `function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
      if ($vars['is_front']) {//for home page
        $vars['title'] = '';
      }
      elseif (!empty($vars['node']) && in_array($vars['node']->type, array('NODETYPE1', 'NODETYPE2'))) {//for specific node type(NODETYPE1 OR NODETYPE2)
        $vars['title'] = '';
      }
  }`
- You can also use [template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7)

  `function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$node) {
        // check for node type
          if(in_array($node['type'], array('NODETYPE1', 'NODETYPE2'))) {//for specific node type(NODETYPE1 OR NODETYPE2)
           $node['title'] = NULL; 
        }
  }`

Answer (score 1):

If you use modules [display suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) or/and [page manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) (part of ctools), you could have more control of all the fields, including the title.

Comment: I have never seen title to be controlled by Manage Display tab..

Comment: Then you may not have looked so close :-) http://picpaste.com/Markering_081-J9Wep7Yw.png

Answer (score 0):

`$title` is not inside the `$node` variable but independent. You will find it inside **page.tpl.php** rather than **node.tpl.php**, where usually we guess at first.

So if you are trying to hide it then you should better do some action on this one or just hide it from your specific **page.tpl.php**.