# Create a Block to display Titles - even pages, view-pages, articles

Tags: views, blocks, theming

In my theme I need to hide the title of content, even the content-type pages and the Views page, and put it in a separate block placed in an other region than the content one.
I figured out how to pick the title from the content-type pages (plain-simple as is) but I figure some difficulties on the View Pages.

How can I hide the title of the node or the page view in the content and put in a block of another region?

Thanks for every answers!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Drupal answers.

1. **How hide a title?** There are a lot of questions that have been answered about this topic. [Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/82371/how-do-i-hide-title-of-a-node) one of them.
2. **How put the title in a block?** You have different ways to achive this goal. if you only want to display the title with a content-type and the title is always in the same place, i would create a template for this content-type.

   Another way to do it, you should build a module that declare a block. The content of this block(the title of the node) has to to be rebuild when a page is requested.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Rufein. Sadly, the most difficult task for me is how to manage Views Page.